# Redux store shape depending on another state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am developing an app using React and Redux which has, over time, evolved two *modes*, which have different state shapes. The modes are mutually exclusive, and the user selects the mode when the app loads. The mode is then fixed, and cannot be changed by the user.

The store has simply accumulated state relating to these two modes, but this seems incorrect - the mutual exclusivity of the two modes should surely be reflected in the store shape, and it should only contain state relating to the active mode.

Clearly some kind of conditional logic is required, but I'm not sure how to implement this - I mean this must be a fairly common pattern, but I can't seem to find Redux-based examples. There is a `mode` state entry, and it's the value of this that would determine the store shape. So one part of the store shape is itself dependent on another part of the store state.

I breifly considering having multiple stores, but then dismissed the idea.

Comment: The way *I* would do it would be to store them separately (as they're exclusive) and then reference each slice depending on the logic. That way you keep everything nice and straightforward. Readability/Maintainability > performance IMO tl;dr - Make different mode slices and combine them with `combineReducers` to access each independently based on whatever logic you implmement.

Comment: Does "different state shapes" mean there are different sub-states/slices for each mode? Then I'd agree with @JoelHager - simply group the slices under the mode they belong to. If it's the same slices, but their inner shape is different depending on mode -  a bit more complicated.